# How to use bitquery gql with javascript to get price of a crypto coin

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, graphql-js, gql

I'm trying to get the price of a crypto coin using bitquery gql. I'm a total beginer.

I have a query that is working, and a node server.

My js code is in app.js and when i run `node app.js`, i get: `{ data: { ethereum: { dexTrades: [Array] } } }` i don't know what this means... Is my information inside of that array, or is it just not working properly? How do i go about getting just the "quotePrice" part of my query into a variable?

This is my query that works on graphql.bitquery.io/ide :

```
{
  ethereum(network: bsc) {
    dexTrades(
      options: {limit: 1, asc: "timeInterval.minute"}
      date: {since: "2020-11-01"}
      exchangeName: {in: ["Pancake", "Pancake v2"]}
      baseCurrency: {is: "0x860947ae09058cc028aaf2ac75258060c61f2dfd"}
      quoteCurrency: {is: "0xbb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c"}
    ) {
      timeInterval {
        minute(count: 5)
      }
      baseCurrency {
        symbol
        address
      }
      baseAmount
      quoteCurrency {
        symbol
        address
      }
      quoteAmount
      trades: count
      quotePrice
      maximum_price: quotePrice(calculate: maximum)
      minimum_price: quotePrice(calculate: minimum)
      open_price: minimum(of: block, get: quote_price)
      close_price: maximum(of: block, get: quote_price)
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my app.js file:

```
import fetch from "node-fetch";

const query = `
  {
  ethereum(network: bsc) {
    dexTrades(
      options: {limit: 1, asc: "timeInterval.minute"}
      date: {since: "2020-11-01"}
      exchangeName: {in: ["Pancake", "Pancake v2"]}
      baseCurrency: {is: "0x860947ae09058cc028aaf2ac75258060c61f2dfd"}
      quoteCurrency: {is: "0xbb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c"}
    ) {
      timeInterval {
        minute(count: 5)
      }
      baseCurrency {
        symbol
        address
      }
      baseAmount
      quoteCurrency {
        symbol
        address
      }
      quoteAmount
      trades: count
      quotePrice
      maximum_price: quotePrice(calculate: maximum)
      minimum_price: quotePrice(calculate: minimum)
      open_price: minimum(of: block, get: quote_price)
      close_price: maximum(of: block, get: quote_price)
    }
  }
}

`;
const url = "https://graphql.bitquery.io/";
const opts = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "X-API-KEY": " my bitquery api key "
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        query
    })
};
fetch(url, opts)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Yes, the data you want is most likely in the array. I recommend you learn the [basics of JavaScript Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics) and how to work with them.

Comment: If it helps, try changing `.then(res => res.json())` to `.then(res => res.text())` and see how the returned object is structured.

Comment: yyyeeeeeessss the text returns everything T .T so it's working  okay i will try to find out how to get just that field into a variable. Thank you so much :)

Comment: which node version are you using?